# construct a matrix wanting particular eigenvalues

Tags: eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Is it possible to construct a 3x3 matrix with one negative eigenvalue and two positive eigenvalues? If so, how can this be done?

Comment: $\begin{bmatrix}2&0&0\\0&1&0\\0&0&-1\end{bmatrix}$.

Comment: oh, it is that easy?

Comment: Yes: the eigenvalues of a diagonal matrix are its diagonal entries.